# Match multiple properties in json schema if condition

Tags: jsonschema

I want both properties `country and street_address` to satisfy the conditions in the if condition in schema below.
This is only checking for the first property and not the second property

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "street_address": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "country": {
      "default": "United States of America",
      "enum": ["United States of America", "Canada"]
    }
  },
  "if": {
    "properties": { 
      "country": { "const": "United States of America" },
      "street_address": { "const": "my_address" }
  },
  "then": {
    "properties": { "postal_code": { "pattern": "[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?" } }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you're just missing a `required: ["country", "street_address"]` in your `if` schema. I'll look closer later

Comment: @RaghvendraRao it would help us if you could post data that this does validate but you think it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` schema, "country" and "street_address" are optional. That means that if no "country" is given, then the `if` condition will pass. Same for "street_address". I'm guessing that your intention is that the `if` should pass only if both "country" and "street_address" are present and they have the specified values. So, the solution is to add a `required` keyword to your `if` schema. Then you should get the behavior you're looking for.

```json
"if": {
  "properties": { 
    "country": { "const": "United States of America" },
    "street_address": { "const": "my_address" }
  },
  "required": ["country", "street_address"]
}
```